# Basic math paradox

Tags: paradoxes

1. $1 = 1$
2. $ 1^2 = 1$ and $(-1)^2 = 1$
3. Therefore, $1^2 = (-1)^2$
4. Square root both sides $\sqrt{1^2} = \sqrt{(-1)^2}$
5. Therefore, $-1 =1$

This is an obvious paradox, but I don't know how to approach solving it

Comment: Because you computed the square root incorrectly.

Comment: You made a mistake in your calculation on the RHS in line 4

Comment: $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=1$.

Comment: Generally for real $a$ it's $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ not just $a$ --- the absolute value sign is crucial.

Comment: do you understand what means the notation $f : a \to \sqrt{a}$ ? it means that $f$ is a FUNCTION , which for a number $a$ outputs "its  square root", and clearly $f(1)$ cannot output two different values. sometimes we define the square root of $1$ to be $1$, sometimes to be $-1$, but once we chose the value of $f(1)$, we cannot change anymore (without defining another function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not obvious and wrong. You applied that "if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x=y$ for all $x,y$ in $\operatorname{dom} f$" between step 4 and 5. However, it is true if and only if $f$ is one-to-one. $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2}$ is not one-to-one.